# How do we set the position of an Excel chart from C#?

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I am trying to generate an Excel chart from C#. Chart is generated just find but it allways appears at the center of the screen. How can I set the position of the chart?

Thanks.

My code looks like this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook ebook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)etablo.Workbooks.Add(true);

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet esheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)ebook.ActiveSheet;

_Chart grafik1 = (Chart)ebook.Charts.Add(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

/* Add Data From Cells here */
/* Then */
grafik1.Location(XlChartLocation.xlLocationAsObject, esheet.Name);
```

Comment: Could you post a super-simplified example of what you are doing now to create the chart? An empty chart would be fine. This would be a useful starting point I think.

Comment: @Mark Byers
Updated. These code was from an example that I have found somewhere. I am not sure if it is right way to do it though

Answer (score 10):

after you generate a chart, you can handle chart as a shape object:

for example:

```
esheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Top = 100;
esheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Left = 250;


// or you can handle shape by index - indexes start from 1 so esheet.Shapes.Item(1).Top
```

i think, you would like to set position right the relevating cells, for example:

```
esheet.Shapes.Item("Chart 1").Top = (float)(double)esheet.get_Range("A5","A6").Top;
```

so ...i hope this will help :)

Luboss

Answer (score 1):

When Adding chart You can use this code to handle it's left, top, width, height.
[use this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196568(v=office.14).aspx)

```
var chartObject = charts.Add(260, 30, 300, 300);
```