# Change Default Chart place in excel

Tags: c#, charts, excel-2007

hi i'm be able to generate chart in excel from C# like this

[image]

i want to setting default chat place in specific cells (example cell E15)

[image]

so far i already try solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191000/how-do-we-set-the-position-of-an-excel-chart-from-c)

```
        Excel.Range chartRange;
        Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)oWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 150);
        Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;

        chartRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("E5", "F13");
        chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange, misValue);
        chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;

        Excel.Range chartPlacementRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("E15", "E15");
        chartPage.Shapes.Item(myChart.Name).Top = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Top);
        chartPage.Shapes.Item(myChart.Name).Left = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Left);
        //chartPage.Shapes.Item(myChart).Top = 100;
        //chartPage.Shapes.Item(myChart).Left = 100;
```

but i get error **'parameter incorect'**

i try solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492434/c-sharp-excel-chart-with-custom-x-axis?rq=1) too
but in my porgram it's not available **'Range'** After type SetSourceData then press space

any idea, how to do it rightly?

---

**update**

i think the incorrect parameter is .item(myChart)
so i change it to .item(myChart.Name) *thanks to Baldrick
but it's give new error
**'the item with specified name wasn't found'**

i try to give myChart name with this code

```
myChart.Name = "test";
//then changed
chartPage.Shapes.Item(myChart.Name = "test").Top = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Top);
```

but it's no work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just:

```
excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(10, 80, 300, 150);
Excel.Range chartPlacementRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("E15", "E15");
myChart.Left = chartPlacementRange.Left;
myChart.Top = chartPlacementRange.Top;
```

Comment: it'w work...you just miss '(float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Top);'
after i add that....i can set chart place anywhere thanks

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
 Excel.Range chartPlacementRange = oWorkSheet.get_Range("E15", "E15");
 chartPage.Shapes.Item(chartPage.Name).Top = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Top);
 chartPage.Shapes.Item(chartPage.Name).Left = (float)((double)chartPlacementRange.Left);
```

Comment: i still get message error parameter incorrect...do you have another solution?

Comment: i think the problem in .item(myChart)...mychart need to replace with something else (correct parameter)

Comment: Try the above edited version. (You need to supply object name or index to the Item method - so I've changed it to supply the name)

Comment: i get new error...'the item with specified name wasn't found'..i try to set myChart.name = "test" and change .item(myChart.Name = "test") but no work

Comment: Maybe try the above edit? (You might need the Chart's name rather than ChartObject's)

Comment: still get same error 'the item with specified name wasn't found'

Comment: I think the debugger's your friend from here. The easiest way is to create it in the old (wrong) place, then record a macro while you move it within Excel. Then you can see which properties are updated and used by looking in the macro editor!